# several problems with ::usage in Mathematica 11

Tags: usage-messages

There seems several bugs of `::usage` in mathematica 11.2

First one is that the drop down ::usage always showing the first assigned ::usage

[image]

You can see that the `::usage` is changed, and `?f` is showing the latest usage, but the drop down is still the first assigned usage. What is more, **even you restart the kernel, the drop down is still showing the old one!** You must close Mathematica completely and restart to get rid of this problem. (this behavior is also reproduced in MMA 11.1 linux version)

Second, I found that if there is Chinese word in the usage, than the drop down will show "$failed at the first line", for example

```
ClearAll[test]
test::usage = "
  测试";
test[x_, y_] := Module[{}, xy];
?test
```

will show

[image]

Comment: The failure to update the dropdown template has been around since it was introduced in 9.0.

Comment: @QuantumDot What? Then, no one noticed it? I am just starting using `::usage`...